# Reading feather file into GeoPandas dataframe from URL

Tags: geopandas, feather

I'm trying to read a feather file hosted on IPFS into a GeoPandas dataframe. When executing

```
df = gpd.read_file('https://bafybeiabejz3zbxnegvnprjia3gjosgmopzbuf2iacnwdivcs5kgonemsa.ipfs.w3s.link/ipfs/bafybeiabejz3zbxnegvnprjia3gjosgmopzbuf2iacnwdivcs5kgonemsa/national_grazing_allotments.feather')
```

I'm seeing the following error

```
DriverError: '/vsicurl/https://bafybeiabejz3zbxnegvnprjia3gjosgmopzbuf2iacnwdivcs5kgonemsa.ipfs.w3s.link/ipfs/bafybeiabejz3zbxnegvnprjia3gjosgmopzbuf2iacnwdivcs5kgonemsa/national_grazing_allotments.feather' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Do I need to explicitly specify the file format somehow? If so, it's not clear to me how to do that from the GeoPandas documentation. Am I correct that this is even possible? It appears that the *read_file* method does take URLs.

Comment: Chrome tells me the file contains malware... so I'm not able to do local tests on it... but the way you can sometimes specify the gdal driver to use for reading is by prefixing the path with <DRIVER>:, e.g. CSV:path/to/file . However, I had a quick look in the gdal code and I don't think it is supported for the feather variant of arrow files.

Comment: The streaming variant of arrow does seem to have a prefix implemented: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/arrow.html